# one example about arrayfun in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab. I have the following code like this:

```
names=arrayfun(@num2str, 1:nseq_all, 'unif', 0);
```

After searching, I understand that arrayfun applies a function to each element of an array. So, I guess in this case, we apply num2str function to each element of the array 1:nseq_all. 'unif' and 0 are the arguments for the function and the corresponding value part. I have trouble to understand this part. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`'unif',0` is shorthand for `'UniformOutput',false`, which means that the output  does not have the same dimensions as the input array `1:nseq_all`.

This is because a string `1` dimensions 1x1, but `124` has dimensions 1x3.

`names` will be a cell array, as a normal numeric array can't contain rows/columns with different numbers of elements.

Be sure to carefully read the [`arrayfun` documentation](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

Answer (score 1):

`'unif', 0` is  shorthand for `'UniformOutput',false`. Note that parameterName/parameterValue pairs in Matlab allow the abbreviation of the parameterName, as long as it doesn't conflict with another possible parameter. In this case `'un',0` would have worked as well. Anyway, what is that option for?

`modifiedArray = arrayfun(function_handle, array)`

applies the function defined in `function_handle` to each element of `array` and returns `modifiedArray`, which is the same size as `array`, and the class of whatever `function_handle` returns. **This syntax can only be used if the output of `function_handle` is scalar**, though class doesn't matter, so the output of `function_handle` can be a scalar structure, i.e. `arrayfun(@(x)struct('field',x),magic(4))` is valid.

`cellArray = arrayfun(function_handle, array, 'UniformOutput', false)`

applies the function defined in `function_handle` to each element of `array` and returns `cellArray`, which is the same size as `array`. Each element of `cellArray` contains the output of a call of `function_handle`. **This syntax *must* be used if the output of `function_handle` is non-scalar** (even if each calculation returns a 1-by-2 array, which is totally uniform), but of course, you can use it with scalar output as well.

In your case, `num2str` returns a character array which is non-scalar if the argument of `num2str` goes above 9. Consequently, you need to set `UniformOutput` to `false`.